# How can I make sure my video card is working properly?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, folding-at-home

**Core Question** How can I ensure that my GeForce GTS 450 is working properly?

**Background:** I have an AlienWare system with dual GeForce GTS 450 in SLI running Windows 7 SP1.  Shortly after I got it, I installed the Folding @ Home GPU client and that seemed to work quite well.

Later, I ran into issues and reformatted the harddrive and reinstalled all the software piece by piece rather than using the straight "Factory Restore" option.  This let me avoid many of the trial programs and other programs that came with it that I never used.  The system works quite nicely, except that the Folding @ Home GPU client will not process anything other than its test unit and gives messages about the core not being available.

I tried the non-GPU F@H client and that seems to work.  The only game I play currently is SW:TOR but that seems to work without problems.  I would like to get the F@H working to contribute again, but my main concern is making certain that my video cards are working properly.

Comment: You need to make sure that ALL of the drivers are installed for the card(s). I recommend hitting up either Dell or NVidia's sites (assuming Dell is where Alienware downloads now live), and getting the very latest drivers.

Comment: @RandolphWest Thanks, I will double check that, but I got the drivers from Dell's site and I beleive I have all of them.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman *never* install graphics card drivers (or any drivers, for that matter) from anywhere *but* the website of the manufacturer who created that particular piece of hardware.  Always use the latest Nvidia-built drivers.  It's likely that your CUDA libraries are outdated or not installed.

Comment: @Breakthrough Thanks.  I installed the latest drivers directly from NVidia and it still does not seem to work correctly